# How can I throw custom error when someone tries to mutate an object that is frozen by me?

Tags: javascript, object, freeze

I need to freeze an object/array so it cannot be mutated in any way. `Object.freeze()` is almost perfect:

```
const arr = [];
const obj = { foo: "bar" };
let frozenArr = Object.freeze(arr);
let frozenObj = Object.freeze(obj);

// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible
frozenArr.push('abc');

// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add property x, object is not extensible
frozenObj.x = 'abc';
```

The problem is, **I would like to throw a custom error that will explain to the developer WHY an object is frozen, how to deal with it, etc...**

I was thinking of using `Proxy` or `Object.defineProperties()` and manually throwing errors in setters,  but I don't want to reinvent the wheel, hence my question here. Maybe someone already have a solution.

Comment: I would advise against it, you are going to throw off other programmers that do know what throws that specific error.

Comment: Hmm, changing the error is as easy as wrapping the `.push()` in a try/catch block and throwing the custom error. And if you define a thin wrapper class around the frozen objects, you can use setters to make sure any call to `.push()` or any assignment gets rerouted through that try/catch block. The hard part is making sure the dev does not freeze their own objects, so either provide a function that Needs to be used by a dev to freeze. Or overwrite Object.freeze. Neither is a good solution though, so I would just drop this and just write the Object.freeze() errors in the documentation.

Comment: There are no native "deep freeze" method. You might have to use proxies or a library (like [immutableJS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/))